# Saving Canvas in onDraw();

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

I'm trying to save the Canvas object in a onDraw() method. 
This is because i'm using a foreach loop in the onDraw method resulting in :
canvas.DrawText (textitem , x,y, textpaint);
(i have to do this because im drawing the text around a masked area)

what im trying now is this :

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
if (hasrun = false)
        {
            for(CustomTextViewDrawItem item : drawItemList)
            {
                canvas.drawText(item.Text, item.X, item.Y, textPaint);
            }

            if (eLabel.backgroundGradient != null)
            {
                canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint);
            }
            canvas.save();
            savedCanvas = canvas ;
        }
        else 
        {
            canvas = savedCanvas; 
        }

        hasrun = true; 
        super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

when debugging I see it looks ok, but comes out empty . 
what would be the best way to get this working ?

Comment: What do you expect from save() function? Maybe you misunderstand how it works.

Comment: yes mice is right, I think you misunderstand the canvas.save().

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? please post the place where you add the `Canvas` to your activity, and how you declare the two canvas fields.

Comment: yes I misunderstood the saving part apparantly.
seemed logical at first. should look into that.
Got it working on Sudar's method now. 

sanjay: this is part of a customclass extending a textview. 
which works fine, but im trying to improve performance and reduce allocation. the bitmap saving improves performance but is mem intensive.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that is because of this:

```
if (hasrun = false)
```

I guess you intend to do this instead:

```
if (hasrun == false)
```

Comment: That's the reason i always write `if ( false == hasrun)` =)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save the bitmap: (I think it is better to call the super.onDraw(canvas); at the start on the method, because your view related drawing will be on top)

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (savedBitmap==null){
            savedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvasToSave = new Canvas(savedBitmap)
            for(CustomTextViewDrawItem item : drawItemList){
                canvasToSave.drawText(item.Text, item.X, item.Y, textPaint);
            }

            if (eLabel.backgroundGradient != null){
                canvasToSave.drawPath(path, fillPaint);
            }
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(savedBitmap, 0, 0, new Paint());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this method seems to be working fine. 
however it does cause new problems.  
    OutofMemoryError's to be precise. 
    External Allocation too large for this process.
so way to many bitmap allocations i guess.

Also , kinda weird, when i put the super.Ondraw(canvas) at the beginning , the backgroud draws just fine but the text won't ?
putting at the end works as intended... why could that be ?

Comment: are you using your code hasrun = false still , then it should be hasrun == false

Comment: changing Config.ARGB_8888 to RGB_565 may save some space